# What's the meaning of the Emacs tab behaviored in IJ? and the behavior of the "cut line backward"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, emacs

The Emacs tab seems like three or four tabs(four spaces for each)， I don't know the usage of it.

and the behavior of the "cut line backward" cuts the current space to the start with the above line?What's the logic?It shouldn't match the meaning "cut up to line end" and named "cut up to line beginning"， they're together.So what is that functionality?  I fully replace these two editings by selecting to start and end，  but if you need deleting the selection，you as well type a space or else. So，the ummatching makes me unhappy.
Appreciate for resorting me!

Comment: Existing action is used in Emacs keymap and mimics Emacs behaviour for 'kill-line' action with negative argument (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html)

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks anyway.

Comment: @y.bedrov What's the Emacs keymap?No found in IJ.It is a concept meaning the way inspired by Emacs?Some keymaps like "kill…" all belong the Emacs keymaps set?

Comment: There is "Emacs" keymap in "Settings/Preferences | Keymap"